# Win api MessageBox alternative that has a set for text-align: center

Tags: c++, winapi, messagebox, text-alignment

As I found out by searching, it is not possible to create a [MessageBox()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) with center-aligned text.

So is there some simple alternative providing the MessageBox() functionality (**including program wait for closing/accepting the box**) that has an option to center-align the text?

Thanks for suggestions/examples.

PS: On Windows7+, using C++ Windows API (compiled in MS Visual Studio 2012)

**EDIT:**

Some useful tips:

1) Express version of Visual Studio does NOT have a resource editor/file create option:

- You do have a **Visual Studio "higher" than express** - [How to: Add a
  Resource File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231537.aspx)
- You have **just Express** version :

  - [How to
    add a resource editor for Express version](https://suite.io/guy-lecky-thompson/8k721g)
  - Free editor
    [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/)
  - This [MSDN forum page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/254f1a84-d9e7-4a76-84f1-57584c6b00ed/resource-editing?forum=Vsexpressvc) contains some other useful tips like:

    > From the 'solution explorer', right-click the *.rc file and select
    >   'open with..', then select 'source code (text) editor' from the list.
    >   You might want to 'set as default' to save you repeating those
    >   intitial steps. Once done, you should be able to manually edit the
    >   resource script within Express.
  - [Free XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm)

2) [Visual Studio C++ how to display a dynamic message (i.e., string) in my About box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196048/visual-studio-c-how-to-display-a-dynamic-message-i-e-string-in-my-about-bo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I found out by searching, it is not possible to create a MessageBox() with center-aligned text.

It is not possible to **create** a center-aligned `MessageBox()` dialog, as the API does not expose an option for that.  But it *is* possible to **manipulate** the standard MessageBox()` dialog with some slight trickery to force it to be center-aligned.

Use [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) to create a [`WH_CBT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx#wh_cbthook) hook for the thread that is calling `MessageBox()` (no DLL needed).  The [hook callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx) allows you to discover the HWND of the dialog that `MessageBox()` creates.  With that, you can manipulate it however you want.  In this case, you can use [`FindWindowEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500.aspx) to get the HWND of the [`STATIC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760769.aspx) control for the dialog's text and then apply the `SS_CENTER` style to it using [`SetWindowLong()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591.aspx). For example:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CenterMsgBoxTextProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_ACTIVATE)
    {
        HWND hDlg = (HWND) wParam;
        HWND hTxt = FindWindowEx(hDlg, NULL, TEXT("STATIC"), NULL);
        if (hTxt)
            SetWindowLong(hTxt, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hTxt, GWL_STYLE) | SS_CENTER);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

```
HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, (HOOKPROC) &CenterMsgBoxTextProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
MessageBox(...);
if (hHook) UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx) instead of `SetWindowsHookEx()`:

```
void CALLBACK CenterMsgBoxTextProc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    HWND hTxt = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, TEXT("STATIC"), NULL);
    if (hTxt)
        SetWindowLong(hTxt, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hTxt, GWL_STYLE) | SS_CENTER);
}
```

```
HWINEVENTHOOK hHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, NULL, &CenterMsgBoxTextProc, GetCurrentProcessId(), GetCurrentThreadId(), 0);
MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("test"), TEXT("test"), MB_OK);
if (hHook) UnhookWinEvent(hHook);
```

Here is what the result looks like in both cases:

[image: proof]

Comment: Tricky, but useful, is it just me or is it a bit off-center? (that would not matter though...) Anyway I was i fact right at all , you can't create such MessageBox but you can force it after creation :)

Comment: The text is centered within the width of the `STATIC` control, but the control itself does not stretch across the entire width of the dialog by default.  However, since you can obtain both HWNDs, you can query the dialog's client width and adjust the control's width as needed.

Comment: Manipulating the `MessageBox()` HWND in this manner is how people used to implement `MessageBoxTimeout()` before it was a standard function, or add custom controls to the dialog (such as a "remember this option" type of checkbox), or customize the button texts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is not. But it is actually quite easy to create such a dialog using Win32 resources and the [DialogBox function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I ment something like that, could you provide and example how to center the text in DialogBox?

Comment: You simply put a STATIC control in your dialog and give it the [Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) SS_CENTER.

Searching for "Win32 example rc" should give you an example. Also if you use MSVC you can just click your dialog together and set that style on the Static control.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a bit lost here, how would I add a STATIC control to a dialogBox ? I just can't find it,

Comment: http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/win32-apps-with-mingw/
look for the "About Dialog" section. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tells me there is also a CTEXT element for centered texts. Also I cannot give you a concrete example as I am currently on Linux.

Comment: Scroll to "About Dialog" section in JS: `document.getElementsByTagName('h3')[9].scrollIntoView()` :)

Comment: Sorry, but no, it's not at all easy to write your own version of a `MessageBox`. There's more to it than simply showing a dialog. For example, when pressing [Ctrl]+C, a standard `MessageBox` will render a text version of its contents to the clipboard. There's more than meets the eye.